# Подскажите как открыть папку где лежит сам файл .exe через список процессов в (listView)?

Tags: c#

Получаю процессы так:

```
Process[] Proc;
void startprocess()
{
   Proc = Process.GetProcesses();
   for (int i = 0; i < Proc.Length; i++)
            {
                  ListViewItem itm2 = new ListViewItem(Proc[i].ProcessName + ".exe");
                  if (!listView1.Items.Contains(itm2))
                  {
                        this.listView1.Items.Add(itm2);
                  }
            }
}
```

Теперь не могу понять как открыть папку к лежащему файлу.

Пытался сделать так:

```
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", @" /select," + item.Text));
        }
```

Но открывает всегда одну и ту же рабочую папку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно узнать полный путь к процессу. Это делается через

```
Proc[i].MainModule.FileName
```

Имея полное имя, можно легко получить каталог:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Proc[i].MainModule.FileName)
```

Comment: Вот только я не пойму где мне его заменять?

Comment: Приглашаю в  [Чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51821/) для решение данной проблемы.